# Comparing Integers in Java

Tags: java, integer

If we have expressions something like the following,

```
Integer x=500;
Integer y=500;

System.out.println(x==y);
```

then, the result of the operation `x==y` will be `false` because we are comparing the object references.

---

If I have a loop for these two variables `x` and `y` something like the following,

```
Integer x=0;
Integer y=0;

for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
{
    System.out.println((x==y)+" : "+x+++" : "+y++);
}
```

then, it displays `true` until the value of both `x` and `y` is `127`. In all other cases (i.e when the value of `x` and `y` is incremented over `127` - when the value of these variables is greater than `127`).

So why does this happen? Is there any specification for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers of the values -128 through +127 are [cached](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching) in the JVM.

Additionally, here is the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) page about it.  Specifically, Section 5.1.7 states

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of boxing of primitive types and it is correct.  Java `Integers` are cached using a flyweight pattern for values up to 128.